# Kettle: Run in Repository with Preview of execution

Tags: pentaho, kettle

**This is my Transformation**
[image]

**Run in local** gives me a good log and allows me to **Preview** results of a step. (eg what went wrong and where, what data do I have in each step)
[image]

When I run it in Repository, it just gives me a link to check status, where logs are present BUT text only and I cannot **Preview Data** in each step.
[image]

Is there any way to get this? (I also have a Carte server running, my code call it to run, but for debugging I need to run from Kettle UI)

Comment: which repository you are using?

Comment: my own pentaho server repo

Comment: i mean file/database/enterprise repository?

Comment: Pentaho BI Server (Community) https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Business%20Intelligence%20Server/7.1/